# Не могу извлечь ссылку на изображение с помощью Selenium из атрибута Style

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium

Задали сделать проект, цель которого парсинг постов из ВК. Нужно парсить айди поста, его текст, ссылки в нем и ссылки на изображения. С айди, текстом и просто ссылками я разобрался, но достать ссылку на картинку я не могу..[image: Фрагмент кода в html].

А вот мой код собственной персоной, проблема в том, что он выводит только width и height... я рассчитывал вывести все содержимое и отрезать лишнее фильтром, оставив только ссылку, но все он не собирается выводить.

```
List<IWebElement> PostsImgLink = chromeDriver.FindElementsByXPath
("//div[@class='page_post_sized_thumbs  clear_fix']").ToList();
for (int k = i; k < i + 1; k++)
{
   textBox1.AppendText("Ссылка изображения: \n" + 
   PostsImgLink[k].GetAttribute("style") + "\n");
}
```

Внимание, знатоки, как мне вытащить только ссылку на изображения с помощью Selenium?

Comment: @НикинаФедин а вы не пробовали использовать официальный SDK? Зачем на Selenium парсить если есть API

Comment: мне надо по ТЗ.

Comment: дайте ссылку на пост вк

Comment: да это не важной какой пост, просто посты из ленты новостей, любые абсолютно, можете попробовать из вашей ленты, код везде будет одинаков, главное, чтобы картинка была

Comment: а в чем проблема вытащить регулярным выражением?

Comment: можно фрагмент кода?